# My development code went missing after GCP cloud shell disruption #20006

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am referring to GCP incident https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/developers-console/20006
I couldn't use GCP's cloud shell for few hours yesterday.

And today i can get into Cloud shell but i was shock that my recent scripts are GONE... i compare with my Google Cloud source repository, i only got back the code as latest around 12 Aug 2020.

What should i do? should i just wait and expect it will restore back my script?

Comment: Use your own local copies, or go to your backups.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a Transient Issue, Google is reporting that cloud Shell is working as expected once again in their [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/169350819)

Checked by myself in my project and I can see all my scripts in Cloudshell so it seems to be working now.

Comment: the project are 100% restored! thanks god that i dont have to manually code again... :)